# How can I add padding to the option of the select?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

> I want to add more padding to the select options

```html
<label>Select:</label>
<select class="form-control " >
<option value="">No</option>
<option value="">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 2):

The **padding property** does not work on the **option element** in all browsers, and it is a limitation of CSS. If you require more advanced styling, you may need to consider using Select2 or any other library that has options to customize the select option.

Answer (score 1):

```css
select{
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px ;
}
```

```html
<label>Select:</label>
<select class="form-control " >
<option value="">No</option>
<option value="">Yes</option>
</select>
```

maybe is this you asked

Comment: padding top and button options have not changed

Comment: @Belen you can add padding in select box 5px to as you want from top and bottom but in options you can't there's limited css for <option> you can see some spacing in firefox browser but in chrome no spacing or padding

Answer (score 0):

```
select{
  padding: 7px 70px 7px 70px ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need a Responsive form, Padding need to use percentage

```
.form-control{
 padding: 1% 1%;
}
```